# Call external application inside a fragment of other application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-tabhost

In my application i have a tabhost with several tabs.
When i select each tab i need to call an external aplication inside a fragment of my aplication. I used this code

```
      Intent i = new Intent();
  PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
  i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.collectivus.schedulegrid");
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  startActivity(i);
```

But the external application override main application instead of opening inside the fragment

Anyone knows if what i need is possible, and if is possible how i can do this.
Thanks by your attention

Comment: Not only is this impossible (per kabuko's answer), but the practice of having activities-in-tabs has been deprecated for over two years.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Android doesn't allow you to open other applications inside fragments. You can't even open *your own* activities (let alone other apps) inside a fragment.